# Why UIDocumentMenu Delegate to self doesn't work?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uidocumentmenuvc

I am following Apple documentation for UIDocumentMenuViewController and the following is my code. importMenu.delegate = self doesn't work and Xcode shows: Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UIDocumentMenuDelegate?' . Please help. Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text", "public.data"], inMode: .Import)

    importMenu.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [UIDocumentMenuDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentMenuDelegate_Protocol/), your `ViewController` must conforms to `UIDocumentMenuDelegate` and must implements `documentMenu:didPickDocumentPicker:`

```
extension ViewController: UIDocumentMenuDelegate {
    func documentMenu(documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        // do stuffs here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your delegation class should extend from `UIDocumentMenuViewDelegate` in the view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentMenuViewDelegate  {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text", "public.data"], inMode: .Import)

    importMenu.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Özgür Ersil, according to the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentMenuViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDocumentMenuViewController/delegate), the type of `delegate` is `UIDocumentMenuDelegate` not `UIDocumentMenuViewControllerDelegate`. and as far as i know there isn't something called `UIDocumentMenuViewControllerDelegate` in `UIKit`